# Download file from sftp after an m3u file order

Tags: scripting, sftp, download

In a ssh server I can connect using sftp. In this server I have a list of mkv files witch is listed in m3u8 playlist.
I want to download the mkvs but I want the download according to the order in the m3u8 playlist.

If I could use sh in sftp I would be able to do someting like:

```
while read line ; do
    if [[ $path != "#"* ]] ; do
        get $path
    fi
done < playlist.m3u8
```

(The `if` test if the line is a comment before download it)

Finaly I like to do someting like the `-i` `wget`’s option:

> **-i *file***
>
> **--input-file=*file***
>
> Read URLs from a local or external *file*.

So, how can I download files with sftp in the order of an m3u playlist?

Answer (score 1):

Use `-b`: `sftp -b`  or `sftp -b -` to read standard input. The batch file (or standard input) should contain `sftp` commands, such as, for example, `get`. See the [manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/sftp.1.html) for details.

```bsh
remote_user='...'
remote_host='...'
playlist_file='...'
while read line; do
    if [[ $line != "#"* ]] ; do
        echo '-get' "$line"
    fi
done < "$playlist_file" | sftp -b - "$remote_user"@"$remote_host"
```

(Warning! Not tested.)